How can I get one grease pencil object to appear inside another?
So, I've been having this issue for the last couple of days and I'm sure its my lack of knowledge on how Grease Pencil Objects work and/or interact with each other.
Let me give some details. I originally sketched out my concept as ONE grease pencil object and separated all the layers according to Inks and Fills. After realizing I would not be able to add effects to just one portion of my artwork (namely, the flames, which is currently the only thing I am animating,) I researched how to move them to their own grease pencil object and was successful in doing so.
But I ran into the issue where I always see the flame outside of the skull... When I attempt to put it under the skull by layering the flame grease pencil object over the skull, I still see it through the skull.
Also, for some reason, although I moved the flame into its own grease pencil object, I see the skull grease pencil layers under the fire collection in the layers panel, and when I switch to the skull in the layers panel, the effects that were previously on the flame now show on the skull...
 
My aim is to only have it showing in the skull's eyes, nose and through the key hole while retaining separate effects on the flame and the skull.
I've included pictures showing what I see. 

Looks like you just encountered the most commonly asked grease-pencil question on BSE. You can easily resolve your issue by enabling z-pass in the properties window.
Go to View Layer $\rightarrow$ Passes $\rightarrow$ Data $\rightarrow$ and check off Z.

Since you have chosen to create overlap with more than one grease pencil object, we have no choice but to enable z-pass for both of your objects. Enabling z-pass allows all grease pencil objects to be treated like 3D objects. That means, grease pencil objects can be placed behind or in front of a 3D object instead of having them drawn over the camera window.
Also, since you only have two grease pencil objects, your quickest fix would be to disable z-pass for the one that will show in front. In this case, your Skull.
Within your Skull, go to Object $\rightarrow$ Viewport Display $\rightarrow$ and check off In Front

As a final note, if you're still curious why you have duplicate empty layers in your original grease pencil object, it is most likely because you chose one of the first two options upon separation.

If you don't want empty copies of layers, separate your new grease pencil with Active Layer instead. Your new separate grease pencil object will not contain the same aftereffects that you applied to the original. So, you will have to reapply them.

I know I am extremely late but thank you! This fixed both of my issues.
